# With Powershell retrieving the Office version (not the build)

Tags: powershell

Anybody found a way retrieving Office version? Not the 16.xxxx but the brand version (2302, 2308,...)

I found this code but I doubt it can be use in my package. Risk of timeout or URL change.

```
# Get version information
$content = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office365-proplus-by-date" -Method Get

# Cast current version to a version
$build = [Version]"16.0.12026.20264"

# Get the version using regex
$content -match "<a href=`"(?<Channel>.+?)`".+?>Version (?<Version>\d{4}) \(Build $($build.Build)\.$($build.Revision)\)"

# Output the data
$output = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Build = $build
    Version = $Matches['Version']
    Channel = ($Matches['Channel'] -split "#")[0]
}

Write-Output $output
# Get version information
$content = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office365-proplus-by-date" -Method Get

# Cast current version to a version
$build = [Version]"16.0.12026.20264"

# Get the version using regex
$content -match "<a href=`"(?<Channel>.+?)`".+?>Version (?<Version>\d{4}) \(Build $($build.Build)\.$($build.Revision)\)"

# Output the data
$output = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Build = $build
    Version = $Matches['Version']
    Channel = ($Matches['Channel'] -split "#")[0]
}

Write-Output $output
```

Thanks,

Comment: Try this one it may retrieve
{# Get Office version from registry
$officeVersion = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration").VersionToReport

# Output the version
Write-Output $officeVersion}

Comment: It is returning the build, not the version. Exemple: 2308

Comment: @FrançoisRacine you say this is for "use in my package" - what kind of "package"? Will this be executed on a machine with Office installed, or elsewhere? Where is the input read from?

Comment: During Office installation. So running the install then querying after install.

Answer (score 0):

From reddit, it involves accessing a webpage to lookup the version from the build (it worked for my version 16.0.16130.20644->2302): https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/dcg95q/comment/f2cl7ha/

```
# Get version information
$content = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office365-proplus-by-date" -Method Get

# Cast current version to a version
$build = [Version]"16.0.12026.20264"

# Get the version using regex
$content -match "<a href=`"(?<Channel>.+?)`".+?>Version (?<Version>\d{4}) \(Build $($build.Build)\.$($build.Revision)\)"

# Output the data
$output = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Build = $build
    Version = $Matches['Version']
    Channel = ($Matches['Channel'] -split "#")[0]
}

Write-Output $output


Build            Version Channel
-----            ------- -------
16.0.12026.20264 1909    monthly-channel-2019
```

Comment: Yes this is what I said in my initial post :) But are they any other way from the internal computer (registry, file system, WMI)

Comment: I see you have it there, twice.  You could save the webpage to a file after the first time.

Comment: But I would have to update it frequently.